# Hide / Encapsulate JavaScript Logic

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, actionscript-3, flash

I have a client side application with HTML, JavaScript & Flash. UI interactions involve JS  communicating with Flash using ExternalInterface API.

What would be the best approach to convert the same application to asp.net server side app such that JS logic is hidden i.e. not downloaded to browser. In any case the JS app was supposed to be part of .net app. I understand this approach will introduce latency due to server round-trips, however hiding JS logic is more important. I googled about Server-side javascript (SSJS) but did not get what I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a JavaScript wrapper around the ExternalInterface API that essentially facilitates communication between that and the server.

Answer (score 1):

flash should be able to do everything that javascript can do and more, including network calls. why do you need javascript at all? why not just have flash do all of this logic itself?

of course i'm sure if it's really important, someone could figure out how to reverse engineer your entire flash app haha.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to completely encapsulate javascript logic because it runs on a client machine and due to it being a scripting language is not compiled into executable (essentially - although modern browsers do for performance). You should look at obfuscating and minifying your javascript as this will hide it to some degree - would this help?

David

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide JS from the browser, it is parsed and executed on the client. Obfuscation really isn't worth it as there are tools that will reverse it in seconds.

Just be sure that your server side logic is secure and it doesn't matter if someone reads your JS files. If the logic is business critical then I would suggest using JS to communicate with your server which will perform the logic and supply a response.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but you might have a look at [JavaScript injection in ActionScript 3.0](http://frontenddeveloper.net/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript_and_VBScript_Injection_in_ActionScript_3) using [`ExternalInterface`](http://frontenddeveloper.net/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript_and_VBScript_Injection_in_ActionScript_3). This will hide your JavaScript to a degree though, as other posters have pointed out, not completely.